# Retrofit @Part Multipartbody.Part with @multipart throws exception

Tags: android, retrofit2, multipartform-data, multipart

I am implementing this question [Retrofit @body with @multipart having Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37072368/retrofit-body-with-multipart-having-issue). Everything works great. Problem arises while adding `@Part MultipartBody.Part` file. It throws `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $`. I would appreciate any help.

> NOTE: I am using custom converterFactory and Interceptor (by implementing Gson). Could
>   that be problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Part MultipartBody.Part file. It throws Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $.`

This is GSON error and it means that model that you provided does not match to response you received from your server (In your case you received plane string instead of JSON)

In order to solve your issue please post full response from server so as your model class

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought I screwed it up by adding custom converterFactory. Thanks again )).