# Retrofit 2.0 Multipart Request, send boolean type in form data including file

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am trying to upload a file using retrofit 2.0. Apart from file, I have few other params to be send with form data which include a boolean type also. My request declaration is -

```
@Multipart
    @POST("/upload/abc")
    Call<UploadResponse> uploadToServer(@Part("img_file\";filename=\"image") RequestBody file,
                                             @Part("access_token") RequestBody sessionKey,
                                             @Part("is_final") Boolean isFinal,
                                             @Part("sequence_id") Integer sequenceId,
                                             @Part("entity_id") RequestBody entityId,
                                             @Part("image_type") RequestBody imageType);
```

I am using GsonConverterFactory. I tried 2 approaches -

(1) Instead of `@Part("is_final") Boolean isFinal` I used `@Part("is_final") RequestBody isFinal` and sending it with `RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), String.valueOf(true))`

(2) Using `@Part("is_final") Boolean isFinal` and sending with Boolean.true.

In both the cases, "is_final" received on server side is Unicode or as a String instead of boolean value.

What is the best way to achieve this

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I made it work by -

Add `compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'` to the gradle file.

While creating retrofit instance, add

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("url")
                .client(builder.build())
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

Now you can safely send primitive types with the request.

**Example Request**

```
Call<UploadResponse> uploadFile(@Part("img\"; filename=\"image") RequestBody file, 
                                @Part("session_key") String sessionKey, 
                                @Part("is_final") Boolean isFinal);
```

Call this method using -

```
RequestBody fBody = RequestBody.create(null, someFile);
service.uploadFile(fBody, "some_string_session", true);
```

Comment: After doing that, sending it like this should work? `RequestBody requestVisibility = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), String.valueOf(true));`

Comment: It is a Boolean type. You don't need to convert it to RequestBody. You can simply send 'true' or 'false'.

Comment: @AnkitAggarwal Can you please add the example of request?

Comment: @SANAT added an example.

Comment: @AnkitAggarwal I have already tried the same but it was not working. It is sending as a String.

Comment: After adding '.addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())' it was working perfectly for me.

Comment: There is another way to achieve the same in the form data using retrofit. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48574388/how-to-add-arraylist-of-integers-to-multipartbody/69526098#69526098)

Comment: nothing changed for me `I  Content-Disposition: form-data; name="enabled"
 I  Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
 I  Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
 I  Content-Length: 5
 I  
 I  false`

Comment: @AnkitAggarwal can you please check this example? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75891159/sending-a-boolean-parameter-with-other-parameters-where-one-of-them-is-file-fa