# How to send an Integer value using Multipart.Builder

Tags: java, okhttp

I'm building a RequestBody this way:

```
RequestBody requestBody;
MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder().
.setType(MultipartBody.FORM);

builder = builder.addFormDataPart("key1", "value1");
builder = builder.addFormDataPart("key2", "value2");
etc..
```

However, I now need to add an integer (not an integer value as string).  addFormDataPart only accepts strings. I see that it can also accept another RequestBody, but I can't figure out if that could help me or not.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a string? Presumably the webserver you're talking to is expecting ASCII digits and not 4 bytes in big endian order.

Comment: Server is expecting key3=1  with no quotes around "1"

Comment: Did you find the solution ?

Comment: Found this answer to allow you to pass primitive types https://stackoverflow.com/a/47627526/1767167

Comment: There are only two types can be passed in the form data - Text and File. I don't think you need integer