# How to send List of integers along with image in retrofit2 using Multipart

Tags: android, retrofit2, multipart

I am trying to upload an image using retrofit 2.0., I have few other params to be send with form data which include a List of integers. My request declaration is

```
@Multipart
@POST("/api/Add")
    Call<AddResponse> addApi(@Part("Id") RequestBody id,
                             @Part("Name") RequestBody name,
                             @Part("Description") RequestBody description,
                             @Part("Phone") RequestBody phone,
                             @Part MultipartBody.Part logo,
                             @Part("WorkingDays") RequestBody workingDays,
                             @Part("CitiesIDs") RequestBody cities);
```

```
public class RetrofitService {

    private static Retrofit retrofit;
    private static final Object LOCK = new Object();
    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://baseurl.app";

    public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {

        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.addInterceptor(chain -> {
            Request original = chain.request();

            Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
           .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            Request request = requestBuilder.build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        });

        OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();

        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
        httpClient.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        httpClient.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if (retrofit == null) {
            synchronized (LOCK) {
                retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                        .client(client)
                        .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .client(httpClient.build())
                        .build();
            }
        }

        return retrofit;
    }
```

This way not working as expectedو the list of integers sent separately like below.

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="CitiesIDs"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=290d2964-526a-48b9-b742-c6a3b547c7d6
Content-Length: 286
--290d2964-526a-48b9-b742-c6a3b547c7d6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="CitiesIDs"
Content-Length: 1
7
--290d2964-526a-48b9-b742-c6a3b547c7d6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="CitiesIDs"
Content-Length: 1
8
--290d2964-526a-48b9-b742-c6a3b547c7d6--
```

Also, to convert list of integers to RequestBody i used below way

```
okhttp3.MultipartBody.Builder citiesRequestBodyBuilder = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM);

  for(int i=0; i<citiesIdList.size(); ++i){
  citiesRequestBodyBuilder.addFormDataPart("CitiesIDs", String.valueOf(citiesIdList.get(i)));
   }
```

Since Add a form data part method `addFormDataPart` accept strings only so i had to convert integers to string which make server respond with the below message

```
 {"Success":false,
  "ErrorMessage":"Input string '--290d2964-526a-48b9-b742-c6a3b547c7d6' is not a valid number. Path '', line 1, position 38.",
 "Id":0}
```

Postman, works fine
[image]
So how can i send image and list of integers using Multipart.

The problem is  `RequestBody` only accepts File, byte[], String, ByteString How can I send List of integers With `@part`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: do you facing any error?

Comment: What is the correct way to send image and list of integers to the server using retrofit2?

Comment: first one is correct way

Comment: Add your api call class , request body screenshot and error log.

Comment: @RajasekaranM question updated

Comment: I tried this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47627526/2347794 but it didn't help

Comment: do you need send your  cityIds = ['1","2"] ?

Comment: can you add your postman screenshot for request?

Comment: I need it like [1,2,3] not like ["1","2","3"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use MultipartBody.Part only for file and other field should with RequestBody.

Remove your below code

```
for(int i=0; i<citiesIdList.size(); ++i){
  citiesRequestBodyBuilder.addFormDataPart("CitiesIDs", String.valueOf(citiesIdList.get(i)));
   }
```

Use

```
 // Add other field here
RequestBody description =
            RequestBody.create(
                    okhttp3.MultipartBody.FORM, Gson().toJson(citiesIdList));
```

Comment: it is sent like `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="CitiesIDs"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=5247b2e1-b3ce-409d-bc3b-78c3b9d7fe63
 Content-Length: 168
 --5247b2e1-b3ce-409d-bc3b-78c3b9d7fe63
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="CitiesIDs"
 Content-Length: 5
 [2,5]'                                                                                                          but it gives error `{"Success":false,"ErrorMessage":"Input string '--5247b2e1-b3ce-409d-bc3b-78c3b9d7fe63' is not a valid number. Path '', line 1, position 38.","Id":0}`

Comment: can you check https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server?

Comment: yes i used it for uploading image, question updated with postman screenshot

Comment: use request body instead of okhttp3.MultipartBody.Builder

Comment: like that `RequestBody citiesRequestBody = RequestBody.create("CitiesIDs", new Gson().toJson(cities));` gave create(string, string) error

Comment: why it sees this`[2,5]` as string while it works fine in postman

Comment: actually field only support value as string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207019/discussion-between-rajasekaran-m-and-safa).