# Sending a boolean parameter with other parameters (where one of them is file) fails

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

Server accepts all parameters except boolean one with Multipart form request data

So I have such request:

```
@Multipart
@POST("auth/...")
suspend fun sendExampleRequest(
    @Part("enabled") enabled: Boolean,
    @Part("name") name: String,
    @Part photo: MultipartBody.Part
)
```

Call it from:

```
override suspend fun sendExampleRequest(
    enabled: Boolean,
    name: String,
    photo : Uri
) {
    try {
        withContext(ioDispatcher) {
            authApi.sendExampleRequest(
                enabled = enabled,
                name = name,
                photo = document.toMultipartBodyPart(context, "photo")
            )
        }
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But server responds with error only for boolean parameter that it has the wrong value.

REQUEST:

```
--> POST https://...
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=240f3a38-2e91-4b6c-acd0-c04ba8c0e81a
Content-Length: 68700
accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer ...

--240f3a38-2e91-4b6c-acd0-c04ba8c0e81a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="enabled"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 4
true
--240f3a38-2e91-4b6c-acd0-c04ba8c0e81a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 4
test
--240f3a38-2e91-4b6c-acd0-c04ba8c0e81a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="document"; filename="test_photo_file.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 67794
...
```

RESPONSE:

```
<-- 422 https://... (328ms)
server: nginx
date: Thu, 30 Mar 2023 16:49:08 GMT
content-type: application/json
cache-control: no-cache, private
x-ratelimit-limit: 60
x-ratelimit-remaining: 58
access-control-allow-origin: *
{"message":"The enabled field must be true or false.","errors":{"enabled":["The enabled field must be true or false."]}}
<-- END HTTP (149-byte body)
```

I can just send JSON body instead but without file:

```
{
  "enabled": false,
  "name": "test"
}
```

then it doesn't give error for boolean parameter but of course it gives the error about document file, so I can use only Multipart form to send all needed parameters but there is some issue with boolean parameters

Retrofit setup:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideRetrofit(
    gson: Gson,
    client: OkHttpClient,
    queryConverterFactory: Converter.Factory
): Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
    .client(client)
    .addConverterFactory(queryConverterFactory)
    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create()) // added it but didn't help
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
    .build()
```

Comment: have you tried same api in postman .. if it is working then kindly check code in postman as it is providing this functionality and add SS of code from postman

Comment: @jayeshgurudayalani yes, it's actually a server issue that it accepts only 1/0 when content type is form-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. It's a PHP server issue:

it accepts `1`/`0` only for form-data, a backend dev has to parse `true`/`false` as well