# Update default Content-Type for multipart form-data request in Android

Tags: java, android, retrofit, multipartform-data, okhttp

We are currently using okhttp3 and retrofit2 in Android to make an network api call of type POST with multipart/form-data, the api request and response are as shown below

[image]

If you observe, the request header Content-Type has "`multipart/form-data; boundary=xxxxxx-xxxx-xxx....`"

Following is the code

```
@Multipart
@POST("/some-api-method")
Call<SomeResponseBody> someCreateMethod(@PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> options);
```

I'm facing an issue with sending the customised request header Content-Type as "`multipart/form-data; **charset=utf-8;** boundary=xxxxx-xxxxx-x.....`"
basically i need to update the Content-Type header to accommodate "`charset=utf-8;`"
For this i tried following code

```
@Multipart
@POST("/some-api-method")
@Headers({
        "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8"
})
Call<SomeResponseBody> someCreateMethod(@PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> options);
```

This resulted in addition of "`charset=utf-8;`" to Content-Type, but this resulted in removal or non addition of existing attribute "`boundary=xxx-xxxx.....;`"

basically i need something like below

```
Content-Type : "multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=xxxx-xxx.....;"
```

Any help here to achieve this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to
[Retrofit - Multipart request: Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491096/retrofit-multipart-request-required-multipartfile-parameter-file-is-not-pre/46664184#46664184)
&
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51647665/932044
these pointed me in the right direction and i have fixed my issue in the following way

```
 @POST("/some-api-method")
 Call< SomeResponseBody > someCreateMethod(@Header("Content-Type") String contentType, @Body RequestBody body);
```

I created the MultipartBody object as below

```
RequestBody dataBody = RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MultipartBody.FORM, mGson.toJson(mData));
MultipartBody multipartBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
       .addPart(MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("key1", null, requestBodyObj1))
       .addPart(MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("key2", null, requestBodyObj2))
       .addPart(MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("key3", null, dataBody))
       .build();
String contentType = "multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=" + multipartBody.boundary();
        
someCreateMethod(contentType, multipartBody);
```